# How to construct a github URL that creates a new file?

Tags: github

I would like my application to construct a github url like `https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/new/{branch}/{folder}/{filename}`, which leads to a pre-filled in-browser editor form where the filename is pre-populated. This format is not correct because `{filename}` is not understood to be the name of the file to be created.

For example, when visiting the following URL, github will offer to fork the repo, and take the visitor to the editor, but the filename field is blank, and needs to be manually filled. Github understands `testfile.txt` to be a directory name:

https://github.com/github/docs/new/main/src/testfile.txt

There is a issue which talks about this, but I would still like some reference to documentation:

- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1527

  - `https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/new/{branch}/{folder}?filename={filename}&value={initial content}`